# collectionVV.filterDate is not function error in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I do not know anything to this but I just have one mistake in my code I do not know why:

```
// Load country features from Large Scale International Boundary (LSIB) dataset.
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017');
var roi = countries.filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_co', 'CB'));
Map.addLayer(roi,{},'Cambodia')

//Let's centre the map view over our ROI
Map.centerObject(roi, 6);

// Filter the collection for the VV product from the descending track
var collectionVV = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'))
    .filterBounds(roi)
    .select(['VV'])
    .median();

// Filter the collection for the VH product from the descending track
var collectionVH = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'))
    .filterBounds(roi)
    .select(['VH'])
    .median();

// Adding the VV layer to the map at a specific date
var image = ee.Image(collectionVV.filterDate('2020-10-14', '2020-10-20').median());
Map.addLayer(image.clip(roi), {min: -25, max: 5}, 'Image_VV');
```

For the last line I get:

```
Line 29: collectionVV.filterDate is not a function
```

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 1):

Issue is in **collectionVH**. It is an image; not an ImageCollection because you applied **.median** method in it. So, it is redundant this code line:

```
// Adding the VV layer to the map at a specific date
var image = ee.Image(collectionVV.filterDate('2020-10-14', '2020-10-20').median());
```

You have to change for this one:

```
// Adding the VV layer to the map at a specific date
var image = collectionVV;
```

Complete code is as follows:

```
// Load country features from Large Scale International Boundary (LSIB) dataset.
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017');
var roi = countries.filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_co', 'CB'));
Map.addLayer(roi,{},'Cambodia')

//Let's centre the map view over our ROI
Map.centerObject(roi, 6);

// Filter the collection for the VV product from the descending track
var collectionVV = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'))
    .filterBounds(roi)
    .select(['VV'])
    .median();

// Filter the collection for the VH product from the descending track
var collectionVH = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'))
    .filterBounds(roi)
    .select(['VH'])
    .median();

print(collectionVH);

// Adding the VV layer to the map at a specific date
var image = collectionVV;
Map.addLayer(image.clip(roi), {min: -25, max: 5}, 'Image_VV');
```

and running it in GEE code editor produces following result without any error:

[image]